# $y^{(4)}+3y''-4y=\sinh(x)-\sin^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello to all whom might to assist!
$$
y^{(4)}+3y''-4y=\sinh(x)-\sin^2(x)\\
$$
for the homogenous part i come with the following solutions based on the roots:
$$
s_{1,2}= \pm 1\\
s_{1,2}= \pm i2 \\
thus:\\
y_c = C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}+C_3cos(2x)+C_4sin(2x)
$$
continue to solve for the particular solution i substituted
$$
\sinh(x)-\sin^2(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)\\
$$
so the "guess" for the particular solution is in the form of:
$$
y_p= A+Bxe^x+Cxe^{-x}+Dx\sin(2x)+Ex\cos(2x)
$$
so, my inquiry is basically if i am on the right way, i.e. all what is left is derivative 4 times(!) and to plug in..
or is there simpler way?
Thanks  advance!

Comment: This problem is a doozy...but you are correct!

Comment: The particular solution is $$y_p=-\frac{1}{40} x \sin (2 x)-\frac{1}{400} 13 \cos (2 x)-\frac{9 \sinh (x)}{100}+\frac{1}{10} x \cosh (x)+\frac{1}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path.
$$y^{(4)}+3y''-4y=\sinh(x)-\sin^2(x)$$
$$(y^{(4)}+4y'')-(y''+4y)=\sinh(x)-\sin^2(x)$$
$$z''-z=\sinh(x)-\sin^2(x)$$
Where $z=y''+4y$.

---

Solve the first DE:
$$z''-z=\sinh(x)$$
The guess for the particular solution should be:
$$\implies z_p=Ax \cosh x$$